# How to pass Values to a TextBox in Razor view from JQuery Tree Menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using the example in -

http://codemyne.net/articles/Populating-Treeview-with-checkboxes-using-MVC3Razor-Jstree-Jquery.aspx?visitid=149&type=2

How I can pass the **value or Text of the selected Checkbox** **to a TextBox in the same Razor view page and access that value from the controller**?

Comment: Get the value of selected textbox via jQuery and set the value of textbox to this value. When you post your form, you will get the value of textbox on server.

Comment: My doubt is how to get the selected Checkbox item's Value or Text to a Text Box. I mean I don't know how to pass the selected value to a TextBox in the same page. Do you have any example?
As I mentioned above  I am using the example in this link to display the items - http://codemyne.net/articles/Populating-Treeview-with-checkboxes-using-MVC3Razor-Jstree-Jquery.aspx?visitid=149&type=2
Thanks,